# Validating environment variables in Next.js with Zod

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next.js13, zod

Maybe the resolution is quite simple, but I've been stagnating on it all day.

I'm validating my environment variables with the zod library, which is very famous for validating and transforming data, but I'm getting a persistent error that my environment variables are invalid.

Image of the error:

[image]

My validation scheme:

```js
import { z } from 'zod'

const envSchema = z.object({
  SUPABASE_URL: z.string().url(),
  SUPABASE_KEY: z.string().min(1),
})

const envParsed = envSchema.safeParse(process.env)

if (envParsed.success === false) {
  console.error('❌ Invalid environment variables', envParsed.error.format())

  throw new Error('Invalid environment variables.')
}

export const env = envParsed.data
```

My environment file is .env.local and it has the definitions of my variables.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Are you doing the zod validation on the browser side or the server side? Because according to the documentation, to access env variables in the browser side you need to prefix the env variables with 'NEXT_PUBLIC_'. (I've never used Next before).

Comment: I found this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54866
This explains it a bit https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

Comment: Im thinking about trying this https://github.com/morinokami/next-zodenv

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the same issue. It seems that public environment variables are bundled differently in nextjs, like at compile time. I ended up making it work by explicitly referencing the public variables like so:

```
// lib/env/client.ts

'use client';

const envSchema = z.object({
  NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VARIABLE: z.string(),
})

export default envSchema.parse({
  NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VARIABLE: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VARIABLE,
});
```

Then, on the server, you can do it regularly using the runtime.

```
// lib/env/server.ts

'use server';

const envSchema = z.object({
  PORT: z.coerce.number(),
});

export default envSchema.parse(process.env);
```

Comment: have you tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77749248/6141587)?